# how to get a value of a radio button in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to get the value of a radio button in servlet but am getting null value, below is my jsp code.

```
<td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option1}" />${quest.option1}</td>
```

I have tried using `request.getParameter("quest.questionId");` and `request.getparameter("${quest.questionID}");`but am still getting `null` value.

Comment: what method you are using? get or post?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `${quest.questionId}` is a JSP EL Expression, so it will replace it with the actual question id. 
You have to use `request.getParameter()` by passing the questionId. Not the String parameter.

Otherwise give any other normal name to input like below :

```
<td><input name="questionId" type="radio" value="${quest.option1}" />${quest.option1}</td>
```

then in servlet you can access the value like below :

```
request.getParameter("questionId");
```